# NME Change the window title in C++ and Neko targets

Tags: c++, haxe, nme, neko

I'm using NME to create a small game. I like to display the objective in the title bar in the Neko and C++ targets. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [thread](http://www.nme.io/community/forums/programming-with-haxe/change-window-title-c-and-neko-targets/#11198), NME currently has no way of changing the title at runtime. Hope we get it soon.